# 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH in Python Django

Tags: python, django, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute a Python script in Django. My view file is:

```
def generate_traffic(request):
    #other code
    out = run([sys.executable, 'C://Users//Maisum Abbas//learning_users//trafficapp//traffic.py', "--domain", url, "--thread", requests, "--max-clicks", maximum, "--min-clicks", minimum])
```

If I run the script alone without running it in Django, it works fine. Now, the problem that I am facing is that the script is not able to detect chromedriver if I run it from my function `generate_traffic` in view.py. I don't know what seems to be the problem since the chromedriver is in the same directory as of my other files.

```
myFolder
    -view.py
    -traffic.py (the script I am executing)
    -chromedriver.exe
    -otherfiles
```

Kindly guide me of what I am doing wrong or what seems to be the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chromedriver.exe should be added to the `PATH` environment variable. Apparently, you are using Windows so here are the steps to add it in Windows 10 PATH:

- Search for `View Advanced System Settings` in the start menu and open it.
- Click on the `Environment Variables` button.
- In the newly opened window, choose `Path` and click on `Edit`.
- In the new window, click on `New` to add a new file/dir into `PATH`.
  For your case it should be something like this:
  [image]

Comment: I did it by placing my chromedriver.exe in my Python Scripts, and run it like this: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`. I just have one confusion, what will I have to do in case if I host it somewhere? How should I add chromedriver there?

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked. Just need clarification, will it work fine if I host it somewhere or it will cause error there? If yes, how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Place your chromedriver.exe file in your Python Directory -> Scripts Directory, it will resolve the issue. Then just write it like this in your code:

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

or

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

depending on your use.